# Generic views request handling Django

Tags: python, django, post, get, django-generic-views

I'm relative new in Django. I want to use generic views like this :

```
class photogalleryView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'xxx/photogallery.html'
    model = Foto
    query = Foto.objects.all()

def get_queryset(self):
    return self.query
```

and I definitelly don't know how to handle GET or POST request or something like $_SESSION like in PHP, can you please give me some pieces of advice please ? 
Thank you very much guys !

for example - I want to handle GET request on this URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/photogallery?filter=smth
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, returning the same `QuerySet` object `query = Foto.objects.all()` doesn't make much sense and can (and will) get you into trouble when you try to use filters and pagination. If you want to modify your `QuerySet` manually, do the following:

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    qs = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
    # modify the qs QuerySet in the way you want
    return qs
```

In Django, you don't normally use GET or POST. Django handles it for you :)
The example of what you want to achieve is here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering

In fact, Django documentation is very nice and comprehensive, at least for the public features.
Pay your attention on the `url(r'^books/([\w-]+)/$', PublisherBookList.as_view()),` in the example, where `([\w-]+)` RegEx group captures some argument (e.g. "smith") which you can later use in your `get_queryset` method (as `self.args[0]` in the example).

To understand more about url patterns, read this piece of the documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#named-groups

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/intro/) for class based views, if that's what you want to use.

You can add `get` and `post` [methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/intro/#using-class-based-views) to your class, and they will trigger on each respective request.

These methods take a `request` argument, which can be used to access data from the client, the session, and the logged in user. Check out the docs for details.

Comment: I've already tried, but what these methods should return ? When I try
'return render(request, photogalleryView.as_view(), query)'
It gives me a blank page